# Make audio file start playing with javascript or else?

Tags: javascript, audio

I want an audio file to load paused and then make it to start playing at a given time.

```
<EMBED SRC="home.mp3" HEIGHT="120" WIDTH="400" AUTOSTART="FALSE"></EMBED>
```

I'm using setTimeOut to delay the loading of the file but it makes my file start loading at 10 seconds. I want to have it loaded and ready to play at any moment and then make it play somehow.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the `audio` element?

Comment: no, I don't know how to use it? can you write it in an answer? is that html5? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really check out [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/). You can play sounds very easily.

```
<script src="/path/to/soundmanager2.js"></script>
<script>
  soundManager.url = '/path/to/swfs/';
  soundManager.onload = function() {
    var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
      id: 'someSound',
      url: '/path/to/some.mp3'
    });
    mySound.play();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: does that work in most browsers? I read something of html5 and I don't know how widely supported it is. Thanks

Comment: Yup it works in most browsers. It will use HTML5 features if they are available, but will fall back to flash otherwise.